# Android Push notifications not recieving

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

This is driving me really crazy. I am new to Android development but experienced in iOS development. I wanted to implement Parse Push notifications to an Android app and all is going fine:

- The devices are registered at Parse
- While sending a test Push message the Parse system tells me that the message is received

BUT: I don't receive anything on my Android test devices.

I have already created new Parse Apps and Android Studio projects but without any luck. Any help on debugging this or is this a Android studio related issue?

EDIT: I just followed the Push service quick guide so I added some lines to the Manifest and added this to my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inlog);
       Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx");
        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize("1515015192073818");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.pootentieel.andrew.sbpootentieel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Can you show your GCMIntentService class here..

Answer (score -1):

Did you changed com.parse.starter to match your package name and have you registered push callback receiver activity?

EDIT:
goto this link github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial and import the android project and change the keys. Then run the android project and send a push to see if it works. If it works check both the projects side by side to see what is causing the problem. Please mark this answer as correct if it helped thanks :)

Comment: Yes I did, i rechecked the quick start guide some times.

Comment: goto this link https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial and import the android project and change the keys. Then run the android project and send a push to see if it works. If it works check both the projects side by side to see what is causing the problem. Please mark this answer as correct if it helped thanks :)

Comment: This is not an answer as it asks a question. It should be a comment.